# Web3J library is not supporting in groovy script. I have to send transaction through groovy script and check test load in JMETER

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, groovy, ssl

I have imported all web3J library and using tried using java_version 16,17 and 20. Every time I am facing issue. When I compiled that script in VSCode. I am facing the same issue. Can someone please help me with groovy script?

```
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3j
import org.web3j.protocol.core.DefaultBlockParameterName
import org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService
import org.web3j.tx.RawTransactionManager
import org.web3j.tx.Transfer
import org.web3j.utils.Convert
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.TransactionReceipt
import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials

       def web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService("API_URL"))
       String PRIVATE_KEY = 'b33ccb143751577968f32575ee690eb3873e49f27935708dbdea52fe36b6ba76'
       RawTransactionManager rawTransactionManager = new RawTransactionManager(web3, Credentials.create(PRIVATE_KEY))
       Transfer transfer = new Transfer(web3, rawTransactionManager)
       println "transfer: ${transfer}"


       TransactionReceipt receipt = transfer.sendFunds("0x7de3280c66ecee8f4cbd8fb78850229d8f10d22f", (Convert.toWei("1", Convert.Unit.ETHER).toBigInteger()), Convert.Unit.WEI, 30000, 1000000108).send()

       println("Transaction Hash: ${receipt.transactionHash}")
       println("Block Hash: ${receipt.blockHash}")
       println("Block Number: ${receipt.blockNumber}")
       println("Gas Used: ${receipt.gasUsed}")
       println("Contract Address: ${receipt.contractAddress}")
```

[image: Error message]
[image: Error while compiling in VSCode]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's connected with web3j, I'm getting the same error using simple code like:

```
log.info('Hello from java: ' + System.getProperty('java.version'))
```

[JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) comes with [Groovy 3.0.11](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/gradle.properties#L92) and Groovy 3.0.11 doesn't support Java 20.

Java 17 should work just fine

[image]

For the error you're getting in VSCode it's SSL/TLS protocol versions mismatch between the server and the client, use a tool like [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) to see what protocol(s) does server support and amend your client configuration accordingly.

Comment: I am using Java 17.0.7 and it is working fine and also web3JS is also connected. However, I am getting issue at TransactionReceipt receipt = transfer.sendFunds("0x7de3280c66ecee8f4cbd8fb78850229d8f10d22f", (Convert.toWei("1", Convert.Unit.ETHER).toBigInteger()), Convert.Unit.WEI, 30000, 1000000108).send()